# Bluetooth socket connection with Bluetooth PC server fails "ava.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluecove

I am trying to create a connection between an Android smartphone (Client) with a Bluetooth app (server) running on a PC.

Below is the code snippet for Client

```
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            //tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }


    public void run() {
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {

            mmSocket.connect();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {  
        //Exception caught 
        //java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout,      read ret: -1
        ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Below is the server code (Uses BlueCover jar)

private void waitForConnection() {
        LocalDevice local = null;

```
    StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
    StreamConnection connection = null;

    try {
        local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
        String uuidstr = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
        String uuid_wo_space = uuidstr.replaceAll("-", "");      

        String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid_wo_space  + ";authenticate=false;encrypt=false;name=RemoteBluetooth";
        notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // waiting for connection
    while(true) {
        try {
            connection = notifier.acceptAndOpen();
            Thread processThread = new Thread(new ProcessConnectionThread(connection));
            processThread.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

I have read several links suggesting to change the UUID to "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB", which i have already tried. I have also tried creating a not secure socket using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, which still fails with the same result.

Below is the IOException stack trace

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:900)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:912)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:531)
```

Comment: When i check BluetoothSocket.java, i see the connect method after opening the socket tries to read a channel value from the input stream, which in my case is failing. Not sure what is this channel value and why is it failing for me. Any suggestions regarding this would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for writing a new answer but this way the information is more visible than the reply. Here's an example list of UUIDs for my device:

```
UUID: 0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb          

i   xxxx    Status  Mode
0   110a    N.A.    
1   1105    Connected   Serial Port Protocol (SPP)
2   1106    Connected   File transfer (FTP)
3   1116    N.A.    
4   112d    Connected   Remote SIM mode
5   112f    Connected   Phone book request
6   1112    Connected   
7   111f    Connected   
8   1132    Connected   Message access request
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out on a different PC. I will post the results soon.

Comment: i tried it on a different PC this time, got the same results. The device fails to connect (IOException) and the available UUIDs are null, so it is not able to enumerate the UUIDs either. 

Am i doing something wrong with the server component, can you please review that part ? 

Also, when i check BluetoothSocket.java, i see the connect method, after opening the socket, tries to read a channel value from the input stream, which in my case is failing. Not sure what is this channel value and why is it failing for me.

Comment: Up-voting and accepting this as an answer as i realized this is the right approach for connecting to the UUID's in case the socket connection fails. 

Also suggested, my problem indeed turned out to be an infrastructure issue (on both the PCs i tried). I uninstalled and reinstalled the Broadcom BCM2070 drivers and the connection got established!!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's some really good news, I'm glad that you got this shorted!

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a set of UUIDs that denote different modes of operation like File Transfer (FTP), Remote SIM, Phone book request etc.

You may query and try all the UUIDs on your interface like this:

```
device = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices
            where bd.Name == "YourDeviceName"
            select bd).FirstOrDefault();

Android.OS.ParcelUuid[] parcel = device.GetUuids();

for (int i = 0; i < parcel.Length; i++) {
    socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(parcel[i].Uuid);
    try {
        socket.Connect();
        break;
    }
    catch {
        throw new Exception("Unsupported UUID");
    }
}
```

Also make sure no other device is connected to PC/Android and have an open socket because only one socket can be serviced at a time. You can have as many pairs as you want but only one socket running.

Comment: Thanks for a quick turnaround. I already tried using device.GetUuids(), in my case it returns null. Also, there is no open socket on both PC and Phone.

Comment: When i check the code for BluetoothSocket.Java, i see the code fails here (fails to read channel value from the input stream in connect() method.

        private int readAll(InputStream is, byte[] b) throws IOException {
        int left = b.length;
        while(left > 0) {
            int ret = is.read(b, b.length - left, left);
            if(ret <= 0)
                 throw new IOException("read failed, socket might closed or     timeout, read ret: "
                         + ret);
...
        }

Comment: @Sumeet If there is no UUID coming back from `device.GetUuids()` the you might have an interface failure. You can try running the same code on a different device. I have seen devices with dodgy BT interfaces before. One device in particular was responding with a specific UUID required for the Serial Port Protocol (SPP) but it was unable to establish a socket.